# How to fix Indexing Error using Pytorch Faster-RCNN?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader, faster-rcnn

For a personal project, I am creating a Faster RCNN detector to find the position of a volleyball in gameplay video. To do this, I am using the Volleyball Dataset from M. Ibrahim et al (https://github.com/mostafa-saad/deep-activity-rec). I am also using M. Perez's extension of the ball locations as it is not in the original dataset.

I am basing my code off of pytorch's TorchVision object detection tutorial (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html). As said in the tutorial, I am also using the util files found at https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/main/references/detection.

I am getting an error with indexing using a torch.float32 somewhere in one of the util files. I don't know if it is a problem with the input data or the actual util file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 29
     27 train_loss = train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, train_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=1)
     28 lr_scheduler.step()
---> 29 evaluate(model, val_loader, device=device)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py:115, in context_decorator.<locals>.decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
    112 @functools.wraps(func)
    113 def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
    114     with ctx_factory():
--> 115         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\Documents\Personal\vtracker\engine.py:87, in evaluate(model, data_loader, device)
     85 coco = get_coco_api_from_dataset(data_loader.dataset)
     86 iou_types = _get_iou_types(model)
---> 87 coco_evaluator = CocoEvaluator(coco, iou_types)
     89 for images, targets in metric_logger.log_every(data_loader, 100, header):
     90     images = list(img.to(device) for img in images)

File ~\Documents\Personal\vtracker\coco_eval.py:23, in CocoEvaluator.__init__(self, coco_gt, iou_types)
     21 self.coco_eval = {}
     22 for iou_type in iou_types:
---> 23     self.coco_eval[iou_type] = COCOeval(coco_gt, iouType=iou_type)
     25 self.img_ids = []
     26 self.eval_imgs = {k: [] for k in iou_types}

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pycocotools\cocoeval.py:76, in COCOeval.__init__(self, cocoGt, cocoDt, iouType)
     74 self._gts = defaultdict(list)       # gt for evaluation
     75 self._dts = defaultdict(list)       # dt for evaluation
---> 76 self.params = Params(iouType=iouType) # parameters
     77 self._paramsEval = {}               # parameters for evaluation
     78 self.stats = []                     # result summarization

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pycocotools\cocoeval.py:527, in Params.__init__(self, iouType)
    525 def __init__(self, iouType='segm'):
    526     if iouType == 'segm' or iouType == 'bbox':
--> 527         self.setDetParams()
    528     elif iouType == 'keypoints':
    529         self.setKpParams()

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pycocotools\cocoeval.py:507, in Params.setDetParams(self)
    505 self.catIds = []
    506 # np.arange causes trouble.  the data point on arange is slightly larger than the true value
--> 507 self.iouThrs = np.linspace(.5, 0.95, np.round((0.95 - .5) / .05) + 1, endpoint=True)
    508 self.recThrs = np.linspace(.0, 1.00, np.round((1.00 - .0) / .01) + 1, endpoint=True)
    509 self.maxDets = [1, 10, 100]

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in linspace(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py:121, in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype, axis)
     23 @array_function_dispatch(_linspace_dispatcher)
     24 def linspace(start, stop, num=50, endpoint=True, retstep=False, dtype=None,
     25              axis=0):
     26     """
     27     Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
     28 
   (...)
    119 
    120     """
--> 121     num = operator.index(num)
    122     if num < 0:
    123         raise ValueError("Number of samples, %s, must be non-negative." % num)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

My code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from PIL import Image
```

```
class VolleyballDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, annotation_dir, transform=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.annotation_dir = annotation_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.video_dirs = sorted([int(d) for d in os.listdir(root_dir) if d.isdigit()])
        self.sequence_len = 41
        self.sequence_indices = []
        for video_dir in self.video_dirs:
            frames_dir = os.path.join(annotation_dir, str(video_dir))
            frames = sorted([int(f[:-4]) for f in os.listdir(frames_dir) if f.endswith('.txt')])
            for i in range(len(frames) - self.sequence_len + 1):
                self.sequence_indices.append(frames[i + 20])
        
    def __len__(self):
        return 55
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        video_dir_idx = idx // len(self.sequence_indices)
        sequence_idx = self.sequence_indices[idx % len(self.sequence_indices)]
        video_dir = os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(self.video_dirs[video_dir_idx]))
        sequence_file = os.path.join(self.annotation_dir, str(self.video_dirs[video_dir_idx]), str(sequence_idx)+'.txt')
        with open(sequence_file, 'r') as f:
            line = f.readline()
            while line.startswith('0 0'):
                line = f.readline()
            x, y = [float(coord) for coord in line.split()]
        img_dir = os.path.join(video_dir, str(sequence_idx))
        img_files = sorted(os.listdir(img_dir))
        img_files = [os.path.join(img_dir, f) for f in img_files]
        img_sequence = [Image.open(f) for f in img_files]
        if self.transform:
            img_sequence = [self.transform(img) for img in img_sequence]
        center_idx = len(img_sequence) // 2
        img_tensor = img_sequence[center_idx]
        boxes = []
        boxes.append([x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5])
        
        boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
        labels = torch.ones((1,), dtype=torch.int64)
        image_id = torch.tensor([idx])
        area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
        is_crowd = torch.zeros((1,), dtype=torch.uint8)
        
        print(boxes.shape, labels.shape, image_id.shape, area.shape, is_crowd.shape)
        print(boxes.dtype, labels.dtype, image_id.dtype, area.dtype, is_crowd.dtype)
        print(idx)
        
        target = {}
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["labels"] = labels
        target["image_id"] = image_id
        target["area"] = area
        target["iscrowd"] = is_crowd

        return img_tensor, target


root_dir = 'C:/Users/salba/Documents/videos'
annotation_dir = 'C:/Users/salba/Documents/volleyball_ball_annotation'
dataset = VolleyballDataset(root_dir, annotation_dir, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor())

train_videos = [1, 3, 6, 7, 10, 13, 15, 16, 18, 22, 23, 31, 32, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 48, 50, 52, 53, 54]
val_videos = [0, 2, 8, 12, 17, 19, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 33, 46, 49, 51]
test_videos = [4, 5, 9, 11, 14, 20, 21, 25, 29, 34, 35, 37, 43, 44, 45, 47]

train_idx = [i for i in range(len(dataset)) if dataset.video_dirs[i] in train_videos]
val_idx = [i for i in range(len(dataset)) if dataset.video_dirs[i] in val_videos]
test_idx = [i for i in range(len(dataset)) if dataset.video_dirs[i] in test_videos]

train_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, train_idx)
val_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, val_idx)
test_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, test_idx)
```

```
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FasterRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights
import utils
import torchvision.models.detection as detection
from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate

device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights=FasterRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights.DEFAULT)

num_classes = 2  # ball and background
in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)

params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.005, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=3, gamma=0.1)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

model.to(device)

num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_loss = train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, train_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=1)
    lr_scheduler.step()
    evaluate(model, val_loader, device=device)
```